# How to manage files for a module in ASP.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I built a small module in ASP.net MVC which consists of

- a javascript file
- a css file
- a razor partial view
- a c# model class

If I use the standard way to manage the files, I have to spread them in these folders:

- /Scripts
- /Content/css
- /View
- /Models

I know that MVC is for separating them and it's fine for the application but i my case I would be happier to have all files somewhere together.

There are area's in MVC but I think that's to big for a small module. All I want is to build a small package in my application for the files of this module.

Any good approach for this? How do you handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- /Scripts
- /Content/css
- /View
- /Models

This is just the structure that the default asp.net mvc project template imposes.

You can have any structure you like, but I would recommend keeping your Views and Model separate.

Since our "Model" usually sits in a different assembly our MVC project structure is normally:

- Application (all application infastructure code)
- Content

  - css
  - images
  - scripts
- Controllers
- ViewModels
- Views

Again this is personal preference but I typically like to keep my static assets (css,images,scripts) under one directory.

You can of course separate things out even further. For example if we're using a javascript plugin that has it's own "core" css and images then we normally keep these together e.g.:

- Content

  - css
  - images
  - scripts

    - libs

      - myplugin

        - myplugin.js
        - myplugin.css
        - myplugin.png

Of course as you split things out in this way it can become hard to manage. For this reason we use [Client Dependency Framework](http://clientdependency.codeplex.com/). You could also try [Cassette](http://getcassette.net/).

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. Never thought of using such a Client Dependency Framework, I will try that.